# Videos Stopped Playing Audio From Movie Files

Tags: sound, videos

I have no idea what changed to cause this, but just the day Videos started playing any file I gave it on mute. Other apps are totally unaffected (e.g. Epiphany works as an ugly work around, I can still listen to my music). Restarts did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by clearing Video's state in DConf. Also tried clearing the PulseAudio configuration by deleting the ~/.config/pulse directory, but that didn't appear to have any effect.

Not a very precise answer, but it solved my issue!